# How to upload my custom Jenkins Plugin to a Jenkins Server using a Python Script

Tags: python, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-api

I need to test my custom Jenkins Plug-in `my-plugin.hpi` to a set of Jenkins Servers.

How best can I do it using say a Python Script?

Answer (score 0):

Following Python script uses `requests` module and `Jenkins` HTTP APIs to perform the same.

```
import requests
ciUrl = 'https://jenkins-server-url/my-ci-name'
files = {'file': open('my-plugin.hpi', 'rb')}
headers = {'Authorization':'Basic <base-64-encodeder-username-password>'}
### Uploading the HPI plugin file
r = requests.post(ciUrl + "/pluginManager/uploadPlugin", files=files, headers=headers, verify=False)
### Safe Restart the Jenkins to ensure plugin is installed.
r = requests.post(ciUrl + "/safeRestart", headers=headers, verify=False)
```

print(r.text)

> NOTE 
>   verify=False ensure SSL Validation is turned off. If you are accessing an-unknown Jenkins server, please set verify=True.